# HBase read performance based on row key

Tags: java, hbase

I have inserted 1M rows data into a hbase table. And then I am writing a java program to test the read performance of HBase based on the row key.

```
//create a list which contains 10,000 row keys 
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
   list.add(rowkey);
}

//go through the list and check the rowkey exists in HBase or not
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
{
    Get g = new Get(list.get(i));
    g.setFilter(new KeyOnlyFilter());
    Result r = table.get(g);
    // ...

}
```

rowkey format like "12345_54321". After testing my program, it takes about 50 secs to load all 10,000 row keys to check it exists or not, so every 200/s.

This reading performance is so slow, and I also add the filter into Get object. Is there any other way to improve above performance? or my program has something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The lesser performance is mainly because you are performing a comparison and firing a get in each iteration, I think its obvious that it will take some time, `hbase` was not designed to give you real time performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exists() API to do it.  Here is an example for you, hope it helps.

```
        List<Get> gets = new ArrayList<Get>();
        for (String rowKey : rowKeys) {
            Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
            gets.add(get);
        }

        Set<String> newRows = new HashSet<String>();
        Boolean[] results;
        HTableInterface table = getHTableInterface(tableName);
        results = table.exists(gets);
```